# Stored Procedures and Cursors with SQLFiddle

Tags: mysql

I've developed a small procedure that implements a cursor to update a department's salary based on that department's employee's salary. I would like test this procedure out using SQLFiddle just because it's so convenient, but I cannot seem to figure out how. I've placed the code below underneath the Create Table and Insert lines in the Schema. I have also changed the query terminator to double-slash. It looks as follows:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE updateSalary()
BEGIN
  DECLARE emp_sal, eDno, dDno INT;
  DECLARE dep_cursor SELECT Dno FROM Department;
  DECLARE emp_cursor SELECT Dno, Salary FROM Employee;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

  open dep_cursor;
  department_loop: LOOP
    FETCH dep_cursor INTO dDno;
    IF finished = 1 THEN
      LEAVE department;
    END IF;

    open emp_cursor;

    DECLARE total_sum INT DEFAULT 0;
    employee_loop: LOOP
      FETCH emp_cursor INTO eDno, emp_sal;
      IF eDno = dDno THEN
        total_sum = total_sum + emp_sal;
      END IF;
      IF finished = 1 THEN
        update department SET total_sal WHERE department.dno = dDno;
        LEAVE employee_loop;
      END IF;
    END LOOP employee_loop;
    close emp_cursor;
  END LOOP department_loop;
  CLOSE dep_cursor;
END

DELIMITER//
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1:
```

And my last question is, how do I call this stored procedure in SQLFiddle?

Thank you

Update: Here is the entire schema, I've edited it to use a single slash for termination and I've also changed the query terminator.

```
CREATE TABLE Department (
  Dname varchar(80),
  Dno int primary key,
  Total_sal int,
  Manager_ssn int
)/


CREATE TABLE Employee (
  Name varchar(80),
  SSN int primary key,
  Salary int,
  Dno int references Department(Dno),
  Supervisor_ssn int references Employee(SSN)
)/

ALTER TABLE Department ADD FOREIGN KEY (Manager_ssn) REFERENCES Employee(SSN)/


INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ('John James', 555555555, 5000, NULL , NULL)/
INSERT INTO Department VALUES ('Finance', 20, 7000, 555555555)/
INSERT INTO Department VALUES ('Main', 30, 6000, 555555555)/
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ('Tammy James', 222222222, 6000, 30, 555555555)/
INSERT INTO Department VALUES ('IT', 10, 3000, 222222222)/
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ('John Jones', 111111111, 1000, 10, 222222222)/
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ('Sally Smith', 333333333, 6000, 10, 222222222)/
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ('Tom Jones', 444444444, 3000, 20, 555555555)/
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ('Sue Smith', 666666666, 4000, 20, 555555555)/


CREATE PROCEDURE updateSalary()
BEGIN
  DECLARE emp_sal, eDno, dDno INT;
  DECLARE dep_cursor SELECT Dno FROM Department;
  DECLARE emp_cursor SELECT Dno, Salary FROM Employee;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

  open dep_cursor;
  department_loop: LOOP
    FETCH dep_cursor INTO dDno;
    IF finished = 1 THEN
      LEAVE department;
    END IF;

    open emp_cursor;

    DECLARE total_sum INT DEFAULT 0;
    employee_loop: LOOP
      FETCH emp_cursor INTO eDno, emp_sal;
      IF eDno = dDno THEN
        total_sum = total_sum + emp_sal;
      END IF;
      IF finished = 1 THEN
        update department SET total_sal WHERE department.dno = dDno;
        LEAVE employee_loop;
      END IF;
    END LOOP employee_loop;
    close emp_cursor;
  END LOOP department_loop;
  CLOSE dep_cursor;
END;
/
```

And the new error I am receiving when I try to build the schema is:

```
Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT Dno FROM Department;
  DECLARE emp_cursor SELECT Dno, Salary FROM Employe' at line 4:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a query terminator other than `;`.
Chose it using fourth button from the left, next to `Browser` button.

Please click this link to see how to create and run MySql procedure in SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db743/1

I've used `/`  query terminator in this demo.

```
CREATE TABLE x( x int )/

INSERT INTO x VALUES(1),(2),(3)/

CREATE PROCEDURE update_salary()
BEGIN
  UPDATE x SET x = x + 100;
END;
/
```

**========== EDIT =================**
I use the following procedure while struggling with syntax errors:

The message says that the error is at line 4:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT Dno FROM Department;
>     DECLARE emp_cursor SELECT Dno, Salary FROM Employe' **at line 4:**

First I number lines in the procedure:

```
1. CREATE PROCEDURE updateSalary()
2. BEGIN
3.   DECLARE emp_sal, eDno, dDno INT;
4.   DECLARE dep_cursor SELECT Dno FROM Department;
```

It seems that this line is wrong: `DECLARE dep_cursor SELECT Dno FROM Department;`

To check the syntax of this line I use this checking tool: [checking tool](https://www.google.pl/#q=mysql+cursor+syntax)

This tool shows [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) that the correct syntax should be:

```
DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR select_statement
```

Then I correct the code using the above:

```
 4.   DECLARE dep_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Dno FROM Department;
```

and try to compile the code again.
Now it shows next error at line 5:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT Dno, Salary FROM Employee; END' **at line 5**:

so I repeat the above procedure for line 5 .... and so on, and so on.

Comment: thank you for your response, I have taken your advice and used the single slash but I am still receiving errors. I have edited the original post to reflect my changes and the new error.

Comment: I've edited my answer and show in the answer a method I am using while correcting syntax errors in my code.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for that method. MySQL error messages aren't very helpful at all.